# Is it possible to modify the head?

Tags: javascript, html, head

Is it possible to modify inside the `<head>` using JavaScript after the page is loaded? For example, if I add elements for external style sheets, will that be effective? Or if I change the `<title>`, will that be reflected? If not, are there ways to do this?

Comment: Why didn't you try first?

Comment: @zerkms, well, for one thing, just because it works in the N browsers you might be able to try it on is no guarantee that it will work in browser N+1.  On the other hand, if it were guaranteed behaviour in some spec, that would be a more concrete answer than "yup, it worked when I tried it in Chrome on Linux".

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: right, but from another point of view the question would sound in a different manner, like: I've found that I can do this and this, can anyone confirm it's cross-browser etc etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely.

Although, changing the title is better done with `document.title = "new title here";`

Comment: +1, but you can also change title by innerhtml or text but document.title is preffered way :)