# Which JavaScript SPA frameworks allow changes to <head> elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js, ember.js

In a typical PHP, Python, Rails, etc., web app, like a blog or wiki, it is customary to use the templating language, not only for `<body>` elements but also `<head>` elements like, most obviously the `<title>`. For example, the blog main page may have the blog (site) name and a tagline in the `<title>`, while each post page has a post title followed by the site name. In some cases, you may also want to conditionally add or modify the content of `<head>` elements, such as a `<meta>` tag or a `<link>` to an Atom/RSS feed that you want to exclude from certain pages.

From my research so far, most JavaScript SPA applications tend to be concerned only with `<body>` content (which unarguably is where the action is). AngularJS appears to be alone in showing in its tutorial ([step 3](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03)) the capability to use templating in the `<title>` and even so it comes with caveats. The Ember.js [blog building example by Tom Dale](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QHrlFlaXdI) doesn't even bother with the `<title>` so it ends up reading "Ember Starter Kit" even at the end. In the TodoMVC app, the `<title>` elements are hard-coded for each example, so that doesn't help.

In searching SO for an answer, I found the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207643/is-it-possible-to-modify-the-head) where it was suggested that one should assign to `document.title`. However, that only takes care of `<title>`. If some other tag in the `<head>` needs templating or conditional inclusion, as suggested above, there appears to be no ready-made solution. Is that really the case?

Comment: I don't think you understand the problems that are being solved by MV* architecture or by frameworks that abstract the DOM very well yet. Why would you need a framework in order to change `document.title`? Frameworks don't replace the DOM, or the underlying language or APIs.

Comment: Are you asking for a templating tool that lets you control the `<head>` contents server-side before the original page is served?  Or, since you mentioned single page app, are you just wanting to make dynamic client-side changes to the `<head>` contents via JS in the page?  If the latter, please describe what you want to do that isn't already directly support via javascript (such as `document.title`)?

Comment: providing general support for templating the content of `<head>` would not be too challenging to add to nearly any framework: output a template to a string using the appropriate framework conventions, and set `head.innerHTML`. I suspect the reason updating `<head>` is not a first-class citizen in any framework is because it is a pretty unusual use-case.

Comment: @LukeMelia: I don't think it's so unusual, since blogs typically display a different `<title>` on each post page, but it's not only on blogs. For example, at step 8 of the Angular PhoneCat tutorial, when displaying a single phone, the title is just "Google Phone Gallery", not "{{phone.name}} - Google Phone Gallery". The latter is equivalent to what you would see in any ecommerce site when looking at a particular product.

Comment: @jfriend00: I'm asking for client-side modifications. I gave examples before of changes to other than title: adding a `<meta name="description">`, adding a `<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">` on pages you don't want indexed, or conditionally adding a `<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml">`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I'm not looking for a framework just to change the `document.title`. I want a framework to help me develop a site or app as quickly and effortlessly as possible, otherwise I'd write an SPA in vanilla JS or jQuery. Presenting a different title and meta description on every page is something I've grown accustomed to in non-SPA frameworks (it's mainly for SEO purposes, but it's part of the site nonetheless).

Comment: Do you realize that settings `<meta>` tags with JS is probably not going to influence SEO or crawlers because most search engines don't run JS.

Comment: @jfriend00: I know SEs don't run JS, but I must admit I'm not fully cognizant of the implications of this on SPAs. I've seen some discussions about pushstate vs. hashbang with respect to SEO but haven't really researched that.